# Make h1 decide the div width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the div width to be decided by h1. So the header can be as wide as it wants to be, while the paragraph will only be as wide as the header.

```
<div>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I've heard that this is impossible in plain html/css. Is this true? If so, what would a solution look like?

Comment: header element has display value of block, which means it's width is 100%. So div is going to be 100% as well if not set otherwise. And same goes with div. What you can do, is set div display value to inline-block;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I typically have used a `width:0; min-width:100%;` combo on an internal wrapper to achieve this.  You also need to collapse the width of the `div` by either floating it or setting it to `display:inline-block;`.  It's important to keep the `h1` outside of the wrapper so that it can force the width of the collapsed width `div`.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

p {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}

h1, p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>This is a test</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>This is a test with a very long title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Short</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>This is a test with a title that is absurdly long with the hope that it will wrap in the final result.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works and has solved the issue. Thanks. I can't mark the question as solved, though.

Comment: @Skere You're welcome, and glad I could help.  Not to worry on marking it.  My motivation is in helping other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Set div-s display value to inline-block:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But since h1 has width of 100%(is block element) then it's going to be as wide as some other parent is. If you want heading not to be 100% width then make it aswell inline-block:

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/32/

Comment: The `p` element will still force the `div` to be wider than the `h1` element. Here, `inline-block` doesn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

As said by @Roland Ruul i've added some colours to visualise the fact that `inline-block` is what you need to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5eyd4bv/2/

```
<div>
    <h1>Content goes here</h1>
    <p></p>
</div>

div {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: The `p` element will still force the `div` to be wider than the `h1` element. Here, `inline-block` doesn't help, unfortunately.